# Jenkins Pipeline Conditional Environmental Variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a set of static environmental variables in the `environmental` directive section of a declarative pipeline. These values are available to every stage in the pipeline. 
I want the values to change based on an arbitrary condition. 
Is there a way to do this?

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   environment {
     if ${params.condition} {
     var1 = '123'
     var2 = abc
    } else {
     var1 = '456'
     var2 = def
     }
   }
   stages {
     stage('One') {
      steps {
        script {
        ...
        echo env.var1
        echo env.var2            
        ...
     }
    }
   }
  }
  stag('Two'){
   steps {
        script {
        ...
        echo env.var1
        echo env.var2
        ...
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a stage "Environment" and declare your variable according to the condition you want, something like below:-

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   environment {
     // Declare variables which will remain same throughout the build
   }
   stages {
     stage('Environment') {
                agent  { node { label 'master' } }
                steps {
                    script {
                       //Write condition for the variables which need to change
                       if ${params.condition} {
                                 env.var1 = '123'
                                 env.var2 = abc
                                } else {
                                 env.var1 = '456'
                                 env.var2 = def
                                 }
                        sh "printenv"
                    }
                }
            }
         stage('One') {
          steps {
            script {
            ...
            echo env.var1
            echo env.var2            
            ...
         }
        }
       }
      stage('Two'){
       steps {
            script {
            ...
            echo env.var1
            echo env.var2
            ...
         }
       }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh right, so you can actually set environmental variables within a stage that will be available in other stages. Thanks.

Comment: yes, those variables will be available to all the stages

Comment: When used in a shared lib I get an exception: vars/basePipeline.groovy: 42: expecting '(', found '$' @ line 42, column 28.
                           if ${env.ENABLE_CONSOLE} {

Answer (score 10):

Looking for the same thing I found a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771302/7653022) in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007034/conditional-environment-variables-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline):

Basically is to use the [ternary conditional operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java)

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        var1 = "${params.condition == true ? "123" : "456"}"
        var2 = "${params.condition == true ? abc : def}"
    }
}
```

*Note: keep in mind that in the way you wrote your question (and I did my answer) the numbers are Strings and the letters are variables.*

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we want to use optional params for downstream job if it is called from upsteam job, and default params if downsteam job is called by itself.
But we don't want to have "holder" params with default value in downstream for some reason.
This could be done via groovy function:

###### upstream Jenkinsfile - param `CREDENTIALS_ID` is passed downsteam

```
pipeline {
    stage {
        steps {
            build job: "my_downsteam_job_name",
            parameters [string(name: 'CREDENTIALS_ID', value: 'other_credentials_id')]
        }
    }
}
```

###### downstream Jenkinsfile - if param `CREDENTIALS_ID` not passed from upsteam, function returns default value

```
def getCredentialsId() {
    if(params.CREDENTIALS_ID) {
        return params.CREDENTIALS_ID;
    } else {
        return "default_credentials_id";
    }
}
pipeline {
    environment{
        TEST_PASSWORD = credentials("${getCredentialsId()}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get another level of flexibility, using maps:

```
stage("set_env_vars") {
    steps {
        script {
            def MY_MAP1 = [A: "123", B: "456", C: "789"]
            def MY_MAP2 = [A: "abc", B: "def", C: "ghi"]

            env.var1 = MY_MAP1."${env.switching_var}"
            env.var2 = MY_MAP2."${env.switching_var}"

       }
    }
}
```

This way, more choices are possible.