# Conditional environment variable with interpolation in jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have gone through this [answer] ([Conditional environment variables in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007034/conditional-environment-variables-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline)) and looking for something like below where i need the value of credentials to be set in env variable.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
         TOKEN = env.BRANCH_NAME.equals('master') ? credentials('some-token') : credentials('another-token')
    }
}
```

Is this possible or any other way. pls suggest!

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two more possibilities. First you can use an [if-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56071436/jenkins-pipeline-conditional-environmental-variables) in the `environment` tag. Or you can set the [environment variables dynamically](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#setting-environment-variables-dynamically).

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    environment {
        // Using returnStdout
        CC = """${sh(
                returnStdout: true,
                script: 'echo "clang"'
            )}""" 
        // Using returnStatus
        EXIT_STATUS = """${sh(
                returnStatus: true,
                script: 'exit 1'
            )}"""
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            environment {
                DEBUG_FLAGS = '-g'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'printenv'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the first suggest of using `if-else` inside `environment` but it did not work ```WorkflowScript: 152: Not a valid stage section definition: ``` Will try the second option